# SQL DISTINCT one column, SUM the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, distinct

What I am trying to achieve is to sum the column 'nTxnCount' based on the corresponding DISTINCT values from column 'iSellthruTxnDateKey'.

In a much easier way of telling it. I am trying to find the distinct values of column A, then the values in column B will be summed up.

```
|   A   | B  |
--------------
| Dog   | 1  |
| Cat   | 5  |
| Horse | 10 |
| Horse | 10 |
| Dog   | 1  |
| Snake | 5  |
```

What will happen...

```
|   A   | B  |
--------------
| Dog   | 1  |
| Cat   | 5  |
| Horse | 10 |
| Snake | 5  |
```

End Result..
**21**  which is the sum of the aggregated values above

---

Below is my test query:

```
SELECT ftKPI.sCompanyCode AS 'Country'
        , dmCus.sFQOutletOnlineStore AS 'Outlet Online Store'
        , dmCus.sDistributionChannel AS 'Distribution Channel'
        , dmCus.sGlobalRetailSegmentName AS 'Global Retail Segment'
        , dmCus.sCustomerCode AS 'Customer Code'
        , dmCus.nsCustomerName AS 'Customer Name'
        , SUM(DISTINCT ftKPI.nTxnCount)
    FROM ftRetailKPI ftKPI
        INNER JOIN dmCalendar dmCal (NOLOCK) on ftKPI.iSellthruTxnDateKey = dmCal.iCalendarKey
        INNER JOIN dmProduct dmPRd (NOLOCK) on ftKPI.iProductKey = dmPrd.iProductKey
        INNER JOIN dmCustomer dmCus (NOLOCK) on ftKPI.iCustomerKey = dmCus.iCustomerKey
        INNER JOIN dmProductSalesArea dmPSA (NOLOCK) ON ftKPI.iProductSalesAreaKey = dmPSA.iProductSalesAreaKey
        INNER JOIN ftExchangerate XRate (NOLOCK) on XRate.sYearMonth = '201506' AND ftKPI.sCompanyCode = XRate.sCompanyCode 
    WHERE (ftKPI.sCompanyCode IN ('LSA') OR dmCus.sCountryName IN ('Australia'))
        AND dmPRd.sProductCategoryName IN ('Tops', 'Bottoms', 'Accessories')
        AND dmCus.sDistributionChannel IN ('DI')
        AND dmCus.sGlobalRetailSegmentName IN ('Co. Operated Comm')
        AND dmCus.sFQOutletOnlineStore IN ('First Quality Store')
        AND dmCal.sFiscalYYYY IN ('2015')
        AND dmCal.sFiscalQQ IN ('Q1', 'Q2')
        AND dmCal.sFiscalWeek IN ('Wk01')
        AND dmCus.sCustomerCode IN ('0020017262')
    GROUP BY ftKPI.sCompanyCode
        , dmCus.sCountryName
        --, dmPrd.sBrandName
        , dmCus.sCustomerCode
        , dmCus.nsCustomerName
        , dmCus.nsCustomerNameLocal
        , dmCus.sDistributionChannel
        , dmCus.sGlobalRetailSegmentName
        , dmCus.sRetailSegmentGroupName
        , dmCus.sFQOutletOnlineStore
        , dmCus.sCustomerCode
```

Comment: In your example values in B are not summed...

Comment: so where do you want to display the sum of all ? maybe you don't understand the concept of sql ...

Comment: In my example it is summed up. I mentioned that the end result is 21. I probably don't know much about SQL, but i have the idea of its concept.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i think i know what you want.
You must do this

```
 select sum(colB) from 
 (Select distinct * from tableA) x
```

And DEMO here so you can understand better :[FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2160b/4)

Comment: I added the sub query idea to my actual query. However i am getting a huge amount. In my query i added this, 'JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT iSellthruTxnDateKey,nTxnCount FROM ftRetailKPI) b ON ftKPI.iSellthruTxnDateKey = b.iSellthruTxnDateKey' and added SUM(b.nTxnCount) on the SELECT. Note that iSellthruTxnDateKey = Column A, nTxnCount = Column B

Comment: i really don't get what you are trying to do... and your select is big and has a lot of joins in there ... so i don;t get it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subquery

```
select sum(foo.b)
from (SELECT  distinct on (a) a,b from temp) as foo
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e0b6/17